# Whitelisting ChromeCast: How to turn on developer mode

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, google-cast, chromecast

I just received my ChromeCast and I am wanting to start developing with it.  The problem is that in order to integrate it into your app and use it for testing, your device must be whitelisted.  This process can take up to 5 days and it should be just a simple form to request whitelisting:

https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting

My issue is that in order to register it, I need to retrieve the device's MAC address from the Debug view.  To access the Debug view I have to enable "Developer Mode". Step 2 in the process states:

> On the Apps label, click seven (7) times. The message, "developer mode
>   enabled" appears.

but inside the ChromeCast app there is no Apps label?  Has anyone figured out how to turn on developer mode yet?

**--UPDATE--**

The original instructions on the Whitelisting page were meant for the Android App and I was using the Mac app.  Inside the ChromeCast Android app, if you click the Apps label 7 times it does enable Developer Mode.

Comment: Same boat - no idea how to turn on developer mode on a mac

Comment: I have raised this with the team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Mac version you can find the Chromecast MAC address in Device Settings.

Comment: Thanks Les.. above is a screen cap of my device settings screen.. Where is the MAC address listed?

Comment: We just removed the requirement for a MAC address.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!  Do you know if the concept of "Developer Mode" is gone as well?

Comment: It's in the Android app for sure, I haven't had a chance to look at the others.  Once your Whitelisted, your device has a developer mode where you can debug your Receiver using Chrome Remote.

Comment: Les, that was the clue I've been looking for!  On the Whitelisting page it just said "In the ChromeCast Setup app", it never mentioned the Android app.. So I've been using the Mac version.  The original instructions for enabling Development Mode and getting the MAC address works perfectly in the Android ChromeCast App.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Plug in your Chromecast - make sure it has power and is setup. Download the free "Chromecast" app from Google Play.

The app will find any devices on the network.  As of this writing the app will show what devices it finds at the top of the screen.  At the bottom it show's "Apps" including YouTube, Netflix an Google Play Movies & TV.

If you tap on the "Apps" header 7 times it will put the device into Developer Mode as described.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows version of the chromecast app shows the MAC address to the left of the help button  in the device specific screen even without developer mode.

Comment: I wish they would have thought of that for the Mac version.

Answer (score 0):

In new ChromeCast app click on **DEVICES** Tab 7 times. It will enable devloper mode.